# primitivity of permutation group

Tags: group-theory, gap

If we are to check that extended triangle group $(p,q,r)=<x,y,t: x^p=y^q =t^2=(xy)^r=(xt)^2=(yt)^2=1>$ is primitive, how we can check it in GAP if we have permutation representation of x,y and t already found in GAP for some p, q, r of index subgroup of extended triangle group (p,q,r)?

Secondly, I am confused, what does it mean "G contains a prime cycle v" in Jordans theorem? Is this cycle structure of xy or xyt or $(x^{-1}y)$ in group G? In B. Everitts research papers of "Alternating qoutiets of Fuchsian groups" he consider cycle structure of xy or xyt? I am confused in making sense of the cycle structure for what we are looking for to check the cycle of length $p$ in group G.
I am sorry this might be stupid question regarding prime cycle, however, I could not get the concept behind it. I shall be very thankful if someone could assist me in this aspect.

I tried something like this, that I am sure is wrong something with it

> PrimitiveGroup:=function(perms)
>
> local n,m,x,y,t,g,f;
>
> x:=perms[1];
>
> t:=perms[2];
>
> y:=perms[3];
>
> f:=FreeGroup(3);
>
> g:=f/[x^3,y^7,t^2,(xt)^2,(yt)^2,(xy)^9];
>
> n:=Order(g);
>
> m:=IsPrimitive(g);
>
> Print("Is this group g primitive",m,"\n");
>
> end;

here perms is the permutation represtation that I already got in some program but in the form of as an example like this "[(2,3,4)(5,6,7),(1,2)(3,4),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)]".

I am not sure how could I get the form of fp group from here. However, this is what I have in my mind.

Comment: Have you tried `IsPrimitive`? If yes, then what happened? Could you provide an example in GAP to play with, please?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier for you to debug this, if you would try this without wrapping it into a function first, just interactively: see the first line which fails, and then try to figure out why.

Comment: Furthermore, the major pitfall here lies trying to create a finitely presented group factorising a free group of rank three by the misformed list of permutations (since `xt` should be `x*t` etc). First, you can't create an fp-group that way. Second, you don't have to create it - you want just to generate a permutation group by `x`, `y` and `z`. Then see the manual for `IsPrimitive` and use at least 2-argument version.

Comment: If I have to generate a group by permutations x ,y and t what's the syntex of writing it in GAP? if I cant generate it by factorising a free group.

Comment: The syntax is `Group(x,y,t)` - see the first example from the [GAP Tutorial's chapter on Groups](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap5.htm). And maybe the simplest explanation why factorising a free group by a list of permutations is not possible is that it's a type mismatch.

Comment: I will try this again by using this, Thanks Alexander.

Comment: BTW, in the 1st paragraph, do you want to say that you need to check that the permutation representation of the group $G(p,q,r)$, which is given by images of its generators $x,y,t$,  is primitive?

Comment: Yes thats right, Moreover, I have to check whether it is alternating group or not by using Jordans Theorem, for which I am confused on cheking the prime cycle in Group(x,y,t).

Comment: Ok. Unless you really want to proceed that way, see `?IsAlternatingGroup`, `?IsNaturalAlternatingGroup`, `?StructureDescription` in GAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarising the outcome of the discussion in the comments - this is how to check in GAP that $G$ is a primitive permutation group, and in fact it is a natural alternating group on the points $ \{ 1, ..., 7 \}$:

```
gap> G:=Group((2,3,4)(5,6,7),(1,2)(3,4),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
Group([ (2,3,4)(5,6,7), (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ])
gap> IsPrimitive(G,MovedPoints(G));
true
gap> IsAlternatingGroup(G);
true
gap> IsNaturalAlternatingGroup(G);
true
```

Comment: This might be the case that in GAP IsAlternatingGroup function not be using the Jordan's Lemma. What if we will have to check it by Jordans Theorem. GAP is using the order of the group and chek the alternating group. The problem is I have to test the Jordan's Theorem here.

Comment: I was wondering in the Jordan's lemma how can we find the group contaning the prime cycle of length less than n-3 in GAP.

Comment: @smaz: in GAP, what about calculating conjugacy classes of $G$ and then looking at the cycle structure of their representatives?

Comment: thats right. Thanks, I hope now I can check this property in GAP :)

Comment: @smaz: You're welcome! And since GAP is open-source, you may check what it does in `IsAlternatingGroup` and `IsNaturalAlternatingGroup` in `lib/gpprmsya.gi` file from your GAP installation.